# sails Waterline criteria "complex" conditions

Tags: node.js, criteria, sails.js, waterline

I'm on a Node.js Sails app 0.10-rc4 with Waterline on mongoDB (sails-mongo adapter), and I've a model.where criteria condition that works good:

```
                or:
                [
                    {
                        start: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        },
                        end: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

... but I wanted to add a exception on it, something in algo that's like that :

```
      (
          (startq > startparam AND startq < endparam)
           OR
          (endq > startparam AND endq < endparam)
      )
       OR
      (
          (startq < startparam AND endq > endparam)            
      )
```

... but it seems like we can't use more than one OR ?

```
                or:
                [
                    {
                        start: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        },
                        end: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        },
                        {
                            start: 
                            {
                                '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000)
                            },
                            end: 
                            {
                                '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                ]
```

I've tried many ways (with of without bracket)...

```
                or:
                [
                    {
                        {
                            or:
                            [
                                {
                                    start: 
                                    {
                                        '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                                        '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                                    },
                                    end: 
                                    {
                                        '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                                        '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                                start: 
                                {
                                    '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000)
                                },
                                end: 
                                {
                                    '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

... no one worked, most for the time I got:

```
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

The docs don't have examples on that syntax, there is a way to do it ?

**EDIT:**

Thx to Scott, here is the good syntax:

```
                or:
                [
                    {
                        start: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        end: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        start: 
                        {
                            '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000)
                        },
                        end: 
                        {
                            '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your second two examples are valid JSON, because they include nested objects without keys.  That's why you're getting the syntax error.

The `or` key takes an array of clauses (in the form of valid JSON objects) to "or" together.  Try:

```
            or:
            [
                {
                    start: 
                    {
                        '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                        '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                    },
                    end: 
                    {
                        '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000),
                        '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                    }
                },
                {
                    start: 
                    {
                        '<': new Date(parseInt(req.param('start'))*1000)
                    },
                    end: 
                    {
                        '>': new Date(parseInt(req.param('end'))*1000)
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Note that your original (working) example isn't really doing an "OR", since you're only putting one object in the array.